# Tutorial about sql server and passport

Tags: node.js

I have a question for the great community:
Have you a sample or a tutorial about passport and sql server for the local identification ?
Thanks

Comment: What does the Google say?

Comment: Nothing about sql server and passport

Comment: asking for off-site resources like tutorials are off-topic here

Answer (score 1):

With [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local), you could do a lookup from your SQL Server database using [node-sqlserver](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver).

It would look something like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
         sql.query(conn_str, "SELECT * FROM <user_table> WHERE username=?", [username], function (err, users) {

            //check user's hashed password against the hash of what was passed in

            done(null, users[0]);
        }
    }
});
```